# I can't test a Google App using OpenID single sign-on on the AppEngine devserver, locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps, google-openid

I'm starting to develop an application using App Engine (Python) that will be integrated in the Google Apps platform and will be sold in the Marketplace. I've implemented the Single Sign-On openID authentication and it works fine when deployed, but doesn't work locally at all.

How can i do that locally? `user.federated_identity()` apparently does not work on the localhost.

--edit--
Precisely, what i need to do is to be able to run [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/en/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_python_gae.html) on App Engine's devserver.

Comment: possible hack: change the federated_identity method in google/appengine/api/users.py so that it returns self.__user_id. I believe on localhost all User objects are consider to be fake Google accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On localhost there's no point in verifying that the email matches the federated_id domain, so you should just add this to check_email:

```
def check_email(self, user):
  if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Dev'):
    return True
```

It looks like if your consumer secret and key are set up correctly everything else should work and it will return the first entry from the calendar feed.

Comment: Thank you so much Calvin! Saved me big time. :D